# Unable to get current date in primefaces schedule?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

> When i select a particular date it is showing the previous date I used the same example as in primefaces schedule Can someone show me within a working example how to schedule/mark holidays for that particular month http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/schedule.jsf

Comment: Do you use the **exact** code base shown in the Primefaces showcase? Show us your code (java, xhtml)

Comment: same code as in primefaces

Comment: Show us the code. It works on the Primefaces showcase but not in your project? There must be a difference.

Comment: same code as in primeface same managed bean class and same class as in primefaces

Comment: Then evaluate your http request-responses, javascript console for any hints. We CANNOT help you unless you give us more informatino (=code!)